# Yii1 CGridView - SUM of Custom Column Value in footer

Tags: yii, cgridview

I want Sum of a custom column value in footer

**GridView Code**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'booking-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
         array(
             'name'=>'name',
             'header'=>'User Name',
             'value'=>'$data->booking_id',
             'filter'=>false,
             'footer'=>'Total',
             'footerHtmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-footer'),
         ),
         array(
             'name'=>'id',
             'header'=>'User Fee',
             'value'=> array($model,'GetUserFee'),
             'filter'=>false,
             'footer'=>'' . $model->getTotal($model->search()->getData(), 'id'),
             'footerHtmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-footer'),
         ),
    ),
));
```

**Get Total**

```
public function getTotal($records,$colName){        
        $total = 0.0;

        if(count($records) > 0){
            foreach ($records as $record) {
                    $total += $record->$colName;
            }
        }
        return number_format($total,2);
    }
```

1. Second column value are calculate user fee.
2. In footer sum of User Fee values get the wrong sum. It gives the sum of user ids. and id is table column name.
3. How can I get  the sum of User fee column values

Comment: how does the getTotal method looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a literal representation of `id`, try using the `$data` variable created by CGridView, which actually IS the current record from the `$model` currently being processed in each CGridView iteration.

Your code would then be:

```
array(
    'name'=>'id',
    'header' => 'User Fee',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => '$data->id',
    'filter' => false,
    'footer' => '$model->getTotal($data)',
    'footerHtmlOptions' => array('class'=>'grid-footer'),
),
```

Notice the value of the `type` attribute is set to `raw`.
You can even use a PHP function and pass it the `$data` variable, like so:

```
array(
    'name'=>'id',
    'header' => 'User Fee',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($data) { ... handle $data how you like ... }
    'filter' => false,
    'footer' => '$model->getTotal($data)',
    'footerHtmlOptions' => array('class'=>'grid-footer'),
),
```

For more information check out [special variables in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/252/special-variables-in-cgridview-and-clistview/)